# Relationship results automatically coming out?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a series of relations on my model, here is one of them.

```
class Product extends Model{

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('\App\User');
    }
}
```

I get all rows with:

```
$data = Product::all()
```

And these are looped through like so:

```
 foreach ($data as $value) {
     var_dump($value->title);
 }
```

My understanding was that if you wished for relational data to also come out, you would need to do something like:

```
$data = Product::with('user')->get();
```

But even without the above and just doing an all() I still can access the user:

```
foreach ($data as $value) {
     var_dump($value->title->user);
 }
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Relationship results automatically coming out?

No, basically when you do

```
$data = Product::all();
foreach ($data as $value) {
  var_dump($value->title);
}
```

You are doing this:

```
select * from products
```

But then on your foreach, since you are trying to access a property that wasn't loaded, you are doing a new query, so behind the scenes Laravel is fetching the user. This represents the N + 1 query problem, if you have 25 products you will run 26 queries (25+1):

```
select * from products
select * from users where id = ? (x25)
```

That's why you have the [Eager Loading](http://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) option,

```
$data = Product::with('user')->get();
foreach ($data as $value) {
     var_dump($value->title->user);
 }
```

Doing this you are only running two queries

```
select * from products

select * from users where id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...)
```

So it's up to you to choose which method to use, if you aren't iterating all the products users, then eager loading is unnecessary and the usual `all()` is perfectly fine;